# Iterating through list to print workbook to PDF, but Slicer Selections not updating pivot tables

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook of reports that I update for a list of departments. I iterate through the department list, with formulas looking to the cell I update to update the sheets. Some of the sheets however are pivot tables that are updated via Slicers. Those pivot tables are connected via an OLAP connection.

I have a macro where it selects the slicers for the departments & create copies of the workbook and works properly, but when I iterate the same way, only changing the step where I print to PDF instead of creating a new workbook it seems the pivot tables aren't selecting the slicers. It will choose the first one properly, but every subsequent one doesn't refresh properly. Even weirder, the saving to new files all happens a little after the slicer selection.

I know there's a lot to do with waiting for the connections to refresh and continuing the macro, but the workbook version works fine, so I'm scratching my head why the PDF version doesn't beyond the workbook version taking longer and therefore giving the pivot time to refresh, but all that happens before the section that creates the files.

The section that chooses the slicers is below. Note that I can run this report at two levels, so I have different slicers and the logic is to unselect the higher level if the user chooses so, whereas the other way runs for the more granular level.

```
    If Scenario = "Department" Then
'Department
        Mainbook.SlicerCaches("Group"). _
            ClearManualFilter

        Mainbook.SlicerCaches("Department"). _
            VisibleSlicerItemsList = Array( _
            "[Department].&[" & Code & "]")
        
        Mainbook.SlicerCaches("Department2"). _
            VisibleSlicerItemsList = Array( _
            "[Department].&[" & Code & "]")
    Else
'Group
        Mainbook.SlicerCaches("Department1"). _
            ClearManualFilter
        Mainbook.SlicerCaches("Department2"). _
            ClearManualFilter

        Mainbook.SlicerCaches("Group"). _
            VisibleSlicerItemsList = Array( _
            "[Group].&[" & Code & "]")
    End If
```

I added a section to calculate and wait after the slicer selection, but it still doesn't even select the slicer options seeming to skip over the section of the macro entirely after the first iteration:

```
Calculate
            
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:20")
```